# Disable a compiler-warning project-wide in Qt Creator (when using MSVC)

Tags: c++, qt, visual-c++, warnings, qt-creator

I want to disable a particular warning, such as `C++ warning C4018: '<' : signed/unsigned mismatch`, but project-wide. What do I need to put in my .pro file to achieve that effect?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add the following line to your PRO file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += /wd4996
```

Comment: @DenysRogovchenko What do you mean?