# disable warning qt project with MSVC2015_64bit compiler

Tags: qt, compiler-warnings

I have warning c4100, how can i disable it?

I try it

```
QMAKE_CFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -wd4100 -Wno-unused-parameter
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS_WARN_ON -= -wd4100 -Wno-unused-parameter
```

but it solution doesnt work.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18460943/2674506 ?

Comment: @vahancho thanks, I will try

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
  QMAKE_CXXFLAGS *= -wd4100
```